# How can I evaluate a group of Z-Scores?

Tags: z-score

I have some elements in a dataframe, and for each one of them I have a z-score for some parameters that describe them.

If I wanted to "sum up" all the Z-scores into one value in order to compare each element to one other into the database, how could I do that?

Is there a way to sum Z-Scores or average them and take that number as a comparison value, or should I not use Z-scores at all?

Comment: It would be helpful if you share a chunk of your dataframe

Comment: What is your data? What and why do you want to compare? it sounds like [tag:dimensionality-reduction], e.g. [tag:pca].